# Using $compile in a Directive with a dynamic attribute value

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple Directive, a submit button which should display a loading icon when the button has been submitted. What kind of loading icon depends on an attribute.

The problem is, $compile completely ignores `angular.element('<img ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/{{attrs.icon}}.gif" width="16" height="16">')`

But I don't understand why. The end result is:

```
<img width="16" height="16" class="ng-scope">
```

What am I missing?

**My Code:**

```
ppSubmit.$inject = ['$compile'];
function ppSubmit($compile) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      submitted: '=',
      text: '@'
    },
    template: '<button class="btn" type="submit" ng-transclude></button>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (attrs.type) {
        element.addClass('btn-' + attrs.type);
      }

      var oldText = element.text(),
          // attrs.icon is just a placeholder to demonstrate the issue
          // and will alter be replaced with "attrs.type"
          preloader = $compile(angular.element('<img ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/{{attrs.icon}}.gif" width="16" height="16">'))(scope);

      console.log(attrs.icon);
      console.log(preloader);
      scope.$watch('submitted', function(submitted) {
        element.html(preloader.html() + ' <span>' + (submitted === true ? scope.text : oldText) + '</span>');
      });
    }
  };
}
```

I put up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NLsuVPEyQVAPnknvoJY6?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating this. You want to add an image - just do so in the template and toggle what is shown with `ng-if` (or `ng-show`, if that makes sense)

```
template: '<button ng-if="!submitted" \
                   class="btn" type="submit" ng-transclude></button> \
           <span ng-if="submitted"> \
             <img ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/{{attrs.icon}}.gif" width="16" height="16"> \
             <span>{{text}}</span> \
           </span>'
```

**Addendum**

But more specific to your problem. You compiled `<img ng-src="...">` correctly, which would have worked, but then you just did `.html()`, which takes the HTML-as-string. This HTML string doesn't retain any of the properties of directives (like `ng-src`) that may have been applied

Comment: I have a 20+ submit buttons on my page which do all the same work. Thats why I do a directive for that. And of course I have to use `.html()` how I am otherwise supposed to get the HTML? I also expect from `$compile` to return a compiled string with `ng-src` resolved to `src`.

Comment: @BenjaminSuch, I meant for the HTML above to be the template of your directive (I edited the answer to clarify) - so that should solve your "20+ buttons" issue. As for `.html()` and "get the HTML" - I'm not sure what you mean - the directive's template already includes the HTML that is turned on/off by `ng-if`

Comment: @BenjaminSuch, did this help? Do you still have questions?